# Using a variable across classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have this class:

```
class Player

  attr_accessor :card_pile, :name

  def initialize
    @name = name
    @bust = false
    @card_pile = []
  end

  def bust?
    return @cards.inject(:+) > 21
  end
end
```

I also have this as the beginning of another class

```
def playing_game
    puts "How many players are playing? "
    players_amount = gets.chomp.to_i
      (0...players_amount).each do
        puts ("What is the players name? ")
        @name = gets.chomp
        @players.push(@name)
      end
      @players.each do |each_player|
        @name = Player.new
        while true
          while @name.card_pile.length < 2 do
            new_card = Card.new
            @name.card_pile.push(new_card.value)
          end
          puts(@name.card_pile)
          print @name, "'s turn" "\n"
```

At the moment this will print out `#<Player:0x007fc14984a4b0>'s turn` instead of `Rich's turn`

Why is this happening? I thought I had made an instance variable in the Player class and then instantiated this class `@name = Player.new` and then could reference it from here on out??

Comment: Hint: Your variable names are misleading: `@name` is not a name, it's a `Player`.

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
def playing_game
  puts 'How many players are playing?'
  players_amount = gets.chomp.to_i
  players_names = (0...players_amount).map do
    puts ("What is the players name? ")
    gets.chomp
  end
  players_names.each do |player_name|
    player = Player.new(player_name)
    while player.card_pile.length < 2 do
      new_card = Card.new
      player.card_pile.push(new_card.value)
    end
    puts player.card_pile
    puts "#{player.name}'s turn"
  end
end
```

UPD:

1. You don't need instance variables (like `@name` and `@players` inside single method).
2. In this code you iterate over players names

   @players.each do |each_player|

=>

```
players_names.each do |player_name|
```

3. In context of

   @name = Player.new

name is a Player instance
to create player with given name pass it to initializer:

```
player = Player.new(player_name)
```

then call name on Player instance, that you create earlier

```
puts "#{player.name}'s turn"
```